# What happens when importing a PST file in Outlook for Mac?

Tags: macos, email, ms-office

I recently moved from PC to Mac, and have a legacy of PST archives which I'd like one day to access from the MacOS ecosystem.

The folder structure in Outlook for Mac significantly differs from the PC world, in that my standard folder structure is duplicated in "«`account name`»" (residing on the Exchange server) and "On My Computer" (not residing on the Exchange server).

If I import a PST file, where will the imported data items end up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you import a .PST Windows file into Office 2016 on the Mac the PST file is imported into a folder under the heading "On My Computer." The folder structure is maintained and nothing is uploaded to your exchange server that I could tell.

Also of note is that the data is actually imported, where on Windows the PST file is used as a read/write data store.

You also seem to have access to the calendar and contacts data if that was exported as well.

Comment: Do I get it right that if my PST file has a folder named "D", that I will see a folder named "D" under "On my computer" upon importing the PST file contents?

Comment: Yes you will see that folder

Comment: I just tested it, and the folder structure of the imported PST file indeed appears under "On My Computer", but not the "On My Computer" linked to my on-line account. Instead it appears below my on-line account.